# How to find rotation and translation (transformation matrix) between corresponding points in two different coorinate systens

Tags: c++, opencv, math, coordinate-transformation

I am working on a camera-lidar calibration and I am stuck for some time on the following problem:
 

I am using a usb camera and a 2D lidar. I have the coordinates of the corresponding points in both lidar frame and camera frame (lets say that I have 3 points and their coordinates in lidar frame and the coordinate of the same 3 points in camera frame).

Example for one point:
lidar_pt1(xl, yl)
camera_pt1(xc, yc, zc)
...
are known.

If I hardcode the transformation matrix I get an expected result. Now I am trying not to hardcode it, but to automatically calculate it using the known values of the coordinates. What I have is 3 points in 2D coordinates in the lidar frame and exact 3 points in as 3D coordinates in the camera frame. It is here where I am struggling with the math to somehow calculate the rotation based on the coordinates value that I have. Is there a way to get that rotation? 

camera_pt1 = TransformMat * lidarpt1 
TransformMat = ? 

I saw some examples using SVD (http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671) but I think they require bigger sets of data and the minimum of 3 points would not give the best result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only take 3 pairs of coordinates from each system, then the maths is quite straightforward. Here's a simple example:

```
    |
  4 |                      (R)
    |                       : ',
    |                       :   ',
    |                       :     ',
  3 |                       :      (P)
    |                       :     ,'
    |                       :   ,'
    |                       : ,'
  2 |      (A).....(B)     (Q)
    |       :     ,'
    |       :   ,'
    |       : ,'
  1 |      (C)
    |
    |
    |
  0 +-------------------------------------
    0       1       2       3       4
```

Suppose you have a triangle `ABC` that maps to another triangle `PQR`. You can represent their vertices in [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) as follows:

```
      .-       -.          .-       -.
      | 1  2  1 |          | 4  3  1 |
ABC = | 2  2  1 |    PQR = | 3  2  1 |
      | 1  1  1 |          | 3  4  1 |
      '-       -'          '-       -'
```

You need to find a matrix `M` that maps `ABC` onto `PQR` (i.e., `ABC × M = PQR`). To do this, just multiply `PQR` by the inverse of `ABC`:

```
if    ABC × M  =  PQR,
then  ABC⁻¹ × ABC × M  =  ABC⁻¹ × PQR
so    M  =  ABC⁻¹ × PQR
```

There are plenty of references available on how to invert a 3×3 matrix. This should give you the following result:

```
    .-          -.
    | -1  -1   0 |
M = |  1  -1   0 |
    |  3   6   1 |
    '-          -'
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this makes sense, but can this be done if one known set of points in in 2D and the other in 3D, i.e. will there be missing information about one rotation? We can assume that the z coordinate for a lidar point is zero so we have a lidar point (xl, yl, 0) and corresponding camera point (xc, yc, zc)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that once of the coordinate sets was 3D. In that case, I think you'll just have to drop the z coordinates and treat the camera data as 2D. You can't set the lidar z coordinates to zero because this will make the transformation matrix non-invertible. (You can't invert a 3D⇔2D transformation because it involves throwing information away in one direction, and creating it out of nowhere in the other direction.)