# Find unknown 3D point after rotate,translate and scale a 3D set of points

Tags: math

Hi Guys I have a question.

Let say I have 3 3D points and another "test" 3D point

I know the position of all 4 points.
Now I moving the points to other coordinates but keep their form.

After the points moved, I know all the position points except the test point

What is the best way to find the "test" point?

- I dont know the rotation\transaltion\scale of the move

Example:
Let say I have 3D Points

1. (-6,-55,593)
2. (-4, 11,593)
3. (85,-21,561)

And another "test" Point

1. (81,-25,586)

Now I move all the points but keep their form

1. (-3,23,593)
2. (17,86,592)
3. (94,28,561)

The only point that I don't know is the "test" points.
What is the best way to find the "test" point?

Comment: You have to fix a matrix that (uniformly) transforms the 3 points and then apply that matrix to the 4th point.
There are some smart deductions you can make: 1 if the distances between the points stay the same, there is no scaling.
2 If one of the points stays in place, there is no translation.

Comment: In general case (any kind of affine transformation)  in 3D it is not possible to retrieve unambiguous transformation (and fourth point) having only three pairs of corresponding coordinates. Perhaps your transformations are really limited?

Comment: If it helps, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47098338/1679849) shows how to solve the problem for the 2D case. In 3D, you'll need to invert a 4×4 matrix of four homogenous coordinates. Software like [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index) can do this easily. Other languages should have library functions available for matrix computations.

Comment: Rotation, translation and scaling are not enough. To be sure that there is a combination of rotation, translation and scaling that maps the first three point from set one to the three points from set two, you can check whether the angles of the triangle formed by set one and the angles of the triangle formed by set two are the same. But they are not. There is 1 to 2 degrees difference between the pairs of corresponding angles. So do you need an affine transformation with possibly small distortion?